# C program dynamic memory allocation error, string value issue

Tags: c

I have tried multiple methods for a long time but it didn't work, the output automatically updates all previously entered values for the name.

The `find` method is not required to be checked, but the first display itself provides invalid output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int phone;
    char *name;
} phonecontact;

phonecontact *create(phonecontact *p, int phone, char name[], int i) {
    (p+i)->name = (char *)calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    (p+i)->name = name;
    (p+i)->phone = phone;
    printf("\n%s\n", (p+i)->name);
    return p;
}

void display(phonecontact *p, int i) {
    printf("Name : %s , Phone number : %d\n", p[i].name, p[i].phone);
}

int find(phonecontact *p, char name[], int *num) {
    int phone, i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < *num; i++) {
        if (strcmp(p[i].name, name) == 1)
            display(p, i);
        return 1;
    }
    p = (phonecontact *)realloc(p, ++(*num) * sizeof(phonecontact));
    printf("Enter phone number for entered person : ");
    scanf("%d", &phone);
    p = create(p, phone, name, i + 1);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int num, phone;
    char name[30];
    printf("Enter number of contacts : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    phonecontact *p;
    p = (phonecontact *)calloc(num, sizeof(phonecontact));
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Enter name : ");
        scanf("%s", name);
        printf("Enter phone number : ");
        scanf("%d", &phone);
        p = create(p, phone, name, i);
    }
    printf("\n%s\n", (p)->name);
    printf("\n%s\n", (p + 1)->name);
    printf("\n%s\n", (p + 2)->name);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        display(p, i);
    }
    printf("Enter name of contact : ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    find(p,name, &num);
}
```

Comment: You need to describe the desired behaviour and the actual behaviour.  Otherwise you are leaving us guessing with respect to your question and will get a general code review if anything at all.

Comment: You allocate memory for `(p+i)->name` and immediately overwrite it with `(p+i)->name = name;`. So you just stored the pointers, which all point to the same input buffer. Also, you guessed the length of the name to be `10`. Try `(p+i)->name = strdup(name);` instead of those two lines.

Comment: Aside: never store a phone "number" as an integer. Suppose it begins with one or more zeros, you will lose them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in the code:

- For each contact to have its own `name` string, you must allocate a copy of the `create()` string argument:

```
phonecontact *create(phonecontact *p, int phone, const char *name, int i) {
    p[i].name = strdup(name);
    p[i].phone = phone;
    printf("\n%s\n", p[i].name);
    return p;
}
```

- the function `strcmp()` returns `0` when the strings compare equal, a negative value if the first argument compares less than the second in lexicographical order and a value greater than zero otherwise.

You should use `if (strcmp(p[i].name, name) == 0)` and return 1 only if the strings compare equal.

- It is confusing for a function named `find()` to append a new entry in the array.
- The array reallocated by `find()` is not passed back to the caller, and the previous pointer may have become invalid, causing undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int phone;
    char *name;
} phonecontact;

int flush_input(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

void init_contact(phonecontact *p, int phone, const char *name) {
    p->name = strdup(name);
    p->phone = phone;
}

void display_contact(const phonecontact *p) {
    printf("Name: %s, Phone number: %d\n", p->name, p->phone);
}

int add_contact(phonecontact **pp, int *pnum, const char *name) {
    int phone;
    int num = *pnum;
    phonecontact *p = *pp;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (strcmp(p[i].name, name) == 1) {
            display_contact(&p[i]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    /* reallocate the contact array */
    p = (phonecontact *)realloc(p, (num + 1) * sizeof(*p));
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("cannot reallocate contact array\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Enter phone number for entered person: ");
    while (scanf("%d", &phone) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid input. Try again: ");
        if (flush_input() == EOF)
            return -1;
    }
    init_contact(&p[num], phone, name);
    *pnum = num + 1;
    *pp = p;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int num, phone;
    char name[30];
    printf("Enter number of contacts : ");
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    phonecontact *p = calloc(num, sizeof(*p));
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        if (scanf(" %29[^\n]", name) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Enter phone number: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &phone) != 1)
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        init_contact(&p[i], phone, name);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        display_contact(&p[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter name of contact: ");
    if (scanf(" %29[^\n]", &name) == 1)
        add_contact(&p, *num, name);
    return 0;
}
```